# Overlapping concentric polygons in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, overlap, polygon

I want to create an animation in `Beamer` for approximating the area of a circle with regular polygons. For that, I need to overlap concentric polygons. The animation will be of the overlapping part. I am trying with the following code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]                
                \node [draw, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (0,0) {};
                \foreach \n in {3,...,10}
                \only<+>
                {
                    \node [fill, brown, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n] at (0,0) {};
                }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

On compilation, this is producing the error `File ended while scanning use of \pgffor@next.` If I remove the `\only<+>` part, the code runs fine. How do I get the animation in that case?

**PS.:** Also, I want to join the centre with the vertices of each polygon to break the entire polygon into triangles. How do I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
            \node [draw, minimum size=3cm, circle] {};
            \foreach \n in {3,...,10}
            { % <-- added
            \only<+>
            {
                \node [fill=brown, minimum size=3cm, 
                       regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n] {};
            }
            }% <-- added
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Instruction `only<+>` had to be in group with drawings of nodes, i.e. in your code are missed a pair of curly braces (defining of group). See comments in above MWE.

**Edit:**
For the second question: you need to ad new loop in which you draw lines between center of polygons to their corners. Complete MWE with this loop is:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
            \node [draw, minimum size=3cm, circle] {};
            \foreach \n in {3,...,10}
            {
            \uncover<+> % or \only
            {
                \node (n\n) [fill=brown, minimum size=3cm,
                             regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n] {};
                \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}      % <--- added
                \draw (0,0) -- (n\n.corner \i);% <--- added
            }
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For the last polygon result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Any comment/guidance on joining the vertices?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul, well I try to solve your main problem. For sub question: you need to form new loops in which you draw lines from center of polygons to their corners. I will add this part asap.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually I tried adding one more loop using the `corner` after looking at some answers in this site but could not manage to figure it properly. Where can I find some manual on `corner`?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul, *tikz &pgf manual*, page 792 (section *72.3 Geometric Shapes*, description of *regular polygons*).